# Get angle of elevation?

Tags: java, android, math, accelerometer

From the accelerometer, is it possible to get the angle of elevation? For those of you who don't know, the angle of elevation is:
[image: angle of elevation]
Is this possible with the accelerometer measurements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really possible to get that "elevation angle" to the line of sight since you have no idea where the user is...

What you can do though is assume that the user orients the screen of the device straight towards his eyes.

With that assumption, you can use [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) to get the orientation of the device and get the angle between the y axis and the (x,z) plane.

What it does is that it uses the accelerometer on the 3 axis to see what is the direction of the gravitation force.

This will work only if the device is stationary. If you need to handle it better with motion, you should use the gyroscope if it exists in the device.

Another thing is that depending on your application, you might want to look at some Augmented Reality frameworks if that's the kind of application you are looking into.

**Edit :** Here is some code I put together.
The main function in my code is :

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int sensor = event.type;
    float[] values = event.values;
    int i;
    StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
    // do something with the sensor data
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    float[] R = new float[9]; // rotation matrix
    float[] magnetic = new float[3];
    float[] orientation = new float[3];

    magnetic[0]=0;
    magnetic[1]=1;
    magnetic[2]=0;

    str.append("From Sensor :\n");
    for(i=0;i<values.length; i++) {
        str.append(values[i]);
        str.append(", ");
    }

    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, values, magnetic);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);


    str.append("\n\nGives :\n");
    for(i=0;i<orientation.length; i++) {
        str.append(orientation[i]);
        str.append(", ");
    }
    text.setText(str);
}
```

I did not try on a real device, only on the emulator and using the [SensorSimulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator).

If you want the whole source package with the couple of tools you would need for the sensorsimulator, email me, I have that all packaged.

Instead of making up the magnetic data, you can actually get those from the compass.
What you are looking for is the pitch, that's in `orientation[1]`, it varies between -pi/2 and pi/2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: After I use getRotationMatrix, should I pass the R matrix to getAngleChange?

Comment: Yes, you can use that between a reference "upright" rotation matrix and the one you get from getRotationMatrix. You will still to find which of the three angles you need to use...

Comment: What does an "upright" rotation matrix look like? The application should compare a matrix parallel to the ground, and a different matrix where the user pointed the device at something so that the matrix IS NOT parallel to the ground. How can I get a matrix so that it is parallel with the ground?

Comment: You can get that matrix by using the same function (getRotationMatrix), but instead of giving the data from the accelerometer, you give it [0 0 9.8] for the gravity vector. What you give for the geomagnetic vector does not matter much, something like [0 1 0] should be good. You don't need to care about l either, just the gravity and R.

Comment: Could you please post a very small code sample on the proper use of getRotationMatrix in this situation? And should I pass the I matrix to getInclination or should I pass the R matrix to getAngleChange? I'm sorry for asking for so much, but it would help me understand it much better.

Comment: If you can wait until Monday, I'll try to put some code together then.

Comment: Yes I can wait. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Using that information, how can I get the angle of elevation? As in an angle degree?

Comment: The angle is the pitch, it varies from 0 to pi/2, if you want to change in degrees, just get (orientation[1]*180/pi), that's your angle in degrees.

Answer (score 2):

When measuring movement there is generally no concept of orientation. A multi-axis accelerometer measuring *static acceleration* (acceleration due to gravity) *could* be used to calculate the angle relative the earth.

Most androids phones comes with a number of sensors such as gyroscope etc which can interfaced. See the javadocs for [SensorManager](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) and the various types of [SensorEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html).

Comment: That's actually not true.  They measure acceleration which, when an object no additional forces applied to it, is 9.8m/s/s towards the earth.

Comment: @Chris Thompson, you're right. Multi-axis accelerometers measuring static acceleration *could* be used to get the angle. I think I made a poor generalization.

Comment: right, the key here is multi-axis.  Really, at minimum you'd need three.  Most android devices (in addition to an orientation sensor) have a tri-ax accelerometer

Comment: @Chris, @Johan, How can I be able to utilize the tri-axis accelerometer to find the angle of elevation in my application? Some pseudocode would be fantastic.