# How to get height and width of the object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, camera

I have a project in which i need to get an object's height and width through camera.That is if we open the camera and look the object through camera then object's height and width will displayed in a text box.

can we do this or my idea is ambitious one ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of 'object' is the object whose size you want to determine?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.for example a jug of water then i want the height and width of the jug.

Comment: You want to determine the size of an object *in* the picture?

Comment: Hm ya correct i want the size of the object while viewing from the camera in the application or after the picture taken by the camera.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that.

Comment: @sarath hi, i have same situation to measure object. Did you get the answer? It would be highly appreciated if you share concept with me. :)

Comment: Please refer this  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that only if there is another metric available for you.

For example, user specified that size of particular object **on the same** picture is 1 meter. So by using simple geometry and math you could calculate other sizes. Without such information your problem could be resolved.