# How to measure distance of an object or face from camera

Tags: android, distance

I am working on an application which actually detects the objects or faces and measures the distance from camera to that object or face. I complete the face detection area, now is there any way to measure the distance between detected face from the point where camera is located.

Please Provide any link or source code I have searched a lot but all in vain.

Comment: Guess based on camera's field of view and average size of a face?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera)

Comment: Not based on size of face I think, Just calculate how far is the face from camera.

Comment: Thanks for the link. but not got any idea,

Comment: you need more data points to figure this out @Dave Newton's comment is probably going to give you the most accurate guess with the data you have..

Comment: @Revolution How on earth do you think this is going to work with a single image from a single camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, by tracking the distance between the user's eyes, and how this changes as the face is closer or further from the camera, a fairly accurate idea of the distance from the camera can be obtained.

Android has a built in [face detector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) class that will handle determining where the face is, and even calculate eye separation for you.

A guy did this for his thesis, and posted the code on [github](https://github.com/philiiiiiipp/Android-Screen-to-Face-Distance-Measurement) along with some nice images outlining what it does, a demo video and a link to the paper he wrote.