# how to measure width and height of objects using android camera?

Tags: android

I want to measure the object height and width using android mobile camera. referred lot many links but still I am not able to get any point from that I can start my development.Can anyone give me/suggest me the right way or any example so that I can get more idea about this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera

Comment: Hi @Frink Thanks for giving me the link. I tried to understand all those concept given in that stackoverflow. yet i'm unable to get a point. can you help me with some example source code that gives the object size.

Comment: @amsaraj did you found any solution for that? i

Answer (score 0):

```
 Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters(); // mCamera is a Camera object
 List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

 // position: variable where you choose between different supported resolutions, 
// this varies from phone to phone, even the order can be different, 
// ex. ascending or descending order.

int  mFrameWidth = (int) sizes.get(position).width;
int mFrameHeight = (int) sizes.get(position).height;

//you you need width,height print this mFrameWidth ,mFrameHeight 

 params.setPreviewSize(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
 mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: my scope is to get the objects real size not the size of that object inside photo.