# Compute camera height

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a dataset of images taken by Kinect (RGB+Depth). This dataset is for person detection so I do have the bounding box or/and the skeleton position of the person.

I need to compute or estimate the height of the camera from the floor. Is it possible? if so how?

Comment: Maybe this threat can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera

Comment: I found it before, they use smartphones to do it so they have some other sensors like gyroscope..etc